# Resolving interface using non 1st class

Tags: castle-windsor

When using castle windsor, if we have 2 classes implement same interface and both classes get registered. when we resolve the interface, system always pick up the 1st one. Is it possible to pick up 2nd one based on business rule?

something like we mark each of registrations using different names, later on, when we resolve the interface, we are able to use their name to instantiate it.

Can it be achieved without help of configuration file?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a factory, have a look to TypedFactory facility

Comment: Thanks Cristiano, Can we use Castle Windsor alone to get it done?

Comment: TypedFactory facility is a Castle Windsor feature http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx LMK if you need more